# Generating regex programmatically

Tags: javascript, regex

I find generating regular expressions to be difficult, tedious and error-prone.

Is there a program that can generate a regular expression given input that it must match?

for example, I give the regular expression engine this input:

must match:

```
foo4
baz2
bar8
```

does not match:

```
4
fo4
ba4
barr4
4bar
```

etc.

is this possible for complex regexes or are there too many permutations and it requires a human to guide the algorithm?

Comment: If there was one, then there would be no regex questions on SO.

Comment: unless ppl really loved generating them by hand

Comment: @AlexMills  Oooh ooh! I do!  Also, this wouldn't really be very plausible.  Such an engine would likely spit out retarded results such as `/^(foo4|baz2|bar8)$/` as that would meet your example criteria.

Comment: no, if you wrote smart engine it would be able to generalize, lol

Comment: If there was a do-what-I-mean-machine then there would be no questions at all at StackOverflow. (I am one of the people who loves to write them, but that's not the point. *Programming* is difficult, tedious and error-prone. Regular expressions just behave like any other aspect of making the computer do things for you.)

Comment: regex-magic: http://www.regular-expressions.info/regexmagic.html

Comment: The Regular Expression Generator

Visual Studio 2010 Other Versions 
 https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833197(v=vs.100).aspx